# Substitute all chess pieces in a .o file makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, rules

I have a makefile about a chess project. The current `make Chess` rule looks like this

```
Chess: main.o board.o player.o chess.o square.o piece.o position.o pawn.o rook.o king.o queen.o bishop.o knight.o
    $(CC) main.o board.o player.o chess.o square.o piece.o position.o pawn.o rook.o king.o queen.o bishop.o knight.o $(OUTPUT)
```

and I want to replace it with something like this

```
Chess: main.o board.o player.o chess.o square.o piece.o position.o chesspieces.o
    $(CC) main.o board.o player.o chess.o square.o piece.o position.o  chesspieces.o $(OUTPUT)
```

What I tried :

```
chesspieces.o: ./src/pieces/king.cc ./src/pieces/knight.cc ./src/pieces/bishop.cc ./src/pieces/queen.cc ./src/pieces/pawn.cc ./src/pieces/rook.cc ./src/pieces/piece.cc
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) ./src/pieces/king.cc ./src/pieces/knight.cc ./src/pieces/bishop.cc ./src/pieces/queen.cc ./src/pieces/pawn.cc ./src/pieces/rook.cc ./src/pieces/piece.cc
```

Gives me a bunch of undefined references to `Position, Square, Board`. Piece is the abstract class which every chess piece inherits from and it includes a `Color` and a `Position` class, but I already added rules for those in the `Chess` rule. Should I add them again? Also an extra question: I want to store my object files in a separate folder, will this cause any issues?

Comment: Why do you want this change? It's highly unusual to have one object file per several `.cc` files.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It just made sense to me to add them all together in a .o file. Would also make the Chess rule cleaner

Comment: @EdwardKoulakidis Why do you have a single rule for a class though? Usually you would want a rule per produced binary e.g. one for a library output one for an exe

Comment: Basically, each source file (.cc in the question) gets compiled into a corresponding object file (.o in the question). That's it. You can combine object files into a library, but a library is not an object file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if its even possible to combine many source files into a single object without using weird hacks. `.o` files are separate compilation units and its the linkers job to merge them to create binaries (e.g. libraries).

Your getting undefined references because what your actually doing for `chesspieces.o` is generating an executable called `a.out` (if your using gcc). Use `-c` to generate object files (one per input `.cc` file).

You might want to reorganize your make targets instead, usually you'd have one target per produced binary. e.g. if your making a static library called `foo`:

```
# Rules for pieces/king.o, etc 

foo.a: pieces/king.o pieces/knight.o pieces/bishop.o # ...
  # Combine the object files 
  ar rcs $@ $^
```

So to combine your chesspieces:

```
chesspieces.a: # pieces/king.o ...
    ar rcs $@ $^

Chess: ... chesspieces.a
    $(CXX) ... -lchesspieces -L<dir where chesspieces.a is stored> # Links your chesspiece lib to your Chess executable
```

Note that on Linux static libs are basically just archives of object files so we use `ar` with `rcs` to generate a static library. I've used "magic" make variables `$@` (the target name) and `$^` (the target dependencies). Also we have to pass `-lchesspieces` and `-L<dir>` to the final compilation of `Chess` so the linker can find all the symbols defined in the `.o` files that are part of `chesspieces.a`

Generally during the build a `.o` file is generated for every source (`.cc`) file as an intermediate step between compiling and linking

Note: You tagged your question "cpp" so I changed `CC` to `CXX`, `CC` is the C compiler `CXX` is the c++ compiler

Comment: Cool thank you. Will moving all .o files in an obj directory cause any issues?

Comment: @EdwardKoulakidis Nope, long as you specify the right paths to the `.o` files to the compiler it should be fine

Comment: I added this line to help me move them : `; mv *.o obj` after the chess rule links. Should i change every path in the Chess rule to ./obj/*.o? E.g. : `$(CC) ./obj/main.o ./obj/board.o ... $(OUTPUT) ; mv *.o obj`

Comment: @EdwardKoulakidis What I usually do it just have an `obj` directory which the compiler is invoked in and which gets filled with mess. Then the resultant binaries are copied out at the end. You can use `$^` instead of repeating the dependency list btw :)

Comment: Thank you for you time man,have a  nice day!

Comment: @EdwardKoulakidis Also I had `-l` and `-L` the wrong way round before in the answer, my apologies :p